# Browser not displaying images created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic

So I am building simple html/javascript game. I wrote a script that is rendering 2d array as a grid of images. The thing is it creates all the imgs, assigns class and src correctly, the path seems to be ok but still the images are not being displayed.

Here's the code:

```js
var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var map = [
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
];

var water = 0;
var island = 1;
var pirate = 2;
var home = 3;

var size = 64;

var rows = map.length;
var columns = map[0].length;



function render() {
 for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
  for (var column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
   var cell = document.createElement('img');
   cell.setAttribute('class', 'cell');
   stage.appendChild(cell);
   switch(map[row][column]) {
    case water: cell.src = "../img/water.jpg";
     break;
    case island: cell.src = "../img/island.png";
     break;
    case pirate: cell.src = "../img/pirate.png";
     break;
    case home: cell.src = "../img/home.png";
     break;
   };
   cell.style.top = row * size + "px";
   cell.style.left = column * size + "px";
  }
 }
};

render();
```

```css
#stage {
  position: relative;
  width: 384px;
  height: 384px;
}

.cell {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

p {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id="stage"></div>
 <p id="output"></p>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue with the paths - using an url instead of the path will work:

```
case water: cell.src = "https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300";
```

Which OS is the server running - are you testing local?

Comment: local testing, win10